# Smoothing of experimental data for PCA

Tags: pca, smoothing

I am applying PCA to a set of spectrophotometric measurements with the aim of differentiating two groups of substances. The many small wiggles on the right-hand side of the curves (the region above ~750 nm) are caused almost entirely by noise. So I am wondering whether it would be beneficial to smooth this section of the data before performing a PCA?

What are the consequences of applying PCA to measurements that contain noise on a range of variables? And would smoothing of the experimental data be helpful?

Here are my measurements (top), and the smoothed data using a moving average (bottom):

[image]

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.